# Could it be simpler? map() and filter() on array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way instead of two functions to write only one and get the same result? And, why `map` returns `undefined` values?

```js
let animals = [
  { name: "Fluffykins", species: "rabbit" },
  { name: "Caro", species: "dog" },
  { name: "Hamilton", species: "dog" },
  { name: "Harold", species: "fish" },
  { name: "Ursula", species: "cat" },
  { name: "Jimmy", species: "fish" }
];

let animalsNames = animals.map(animal => {
  if (animal.species === "dog") {
    return animal.name;
  }
});
console.log(animalsNames); // [ undefined, 'Caro', 'Hamilton', undefined, undefined, undefined ]

animalsNames = animalsNames.filter(animal => animal !== undefined);

console.log(animalsNames); // [ 'Caro', 'Hamilton' ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely chain *(combine)* array methods. [Here is a post](https://codeburst.io/javascript-learn-to-chain-map-filter-and-reduce-acd2d0562cd4) with more information on how to do just that.

That said, I don't know much about your application, but I would suggest creating a more practical function.

For example, one where you could specify and/or pass the desired species as an argument and return a list of those names.

```
let animals = [
  { name: "Fluffykins", species: "rabbit" },
  { name: "Caro", species: "dog" },
  { name: "Hamilton", species: "dog" },
  { name: "Harold", species: "fish" },
  { name: "Ursula", species: "cat" },
  { name: "Jimmy", species: "fish" }
];

const getAnimalNamesBySpecies = (species) => {
  return animals.filter(animal => animal.species === species).map((animal) => animal.name)
}

console.log(getAnimalNamesBySpecies("dog"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `map` returns `undefined` values for when the `if` condition is not true. In that case there is no explicit `return` statement executed, which means you implicitly return `undefined`.

There are several solutions. For instance `reduce`:

```js
let animals = [{ name: "Fluffykins", species: "rabbit" },{ name: "Caro", species: "dog" },{ name: "Hamilton", species: "dog" },{ name: "Harold", species: "fish" },{ name: "Ursula", species: "cat" },{ name: "Jimmy", species: "fish" }];

let animalsNames = animals.reduce((acc, animal) => 
    animal.species === "dog" ? acc.concat(animal.name) : acc,
    []
);
console.log(animalsNames);
```

In your original strategy you could simplify the `map` part with some boolean logic, and the `filter` part by just passing `Boolean` as callback function:

```js
let animals = [{ name: "Fluffykins", species: "rabbit" },{ name: "Caro", species: "dog" },{ name: "Hamilton", species: "dog" },{ name: "Harold", species: "fish" },{ name: "Ursula", species: "cat" },{ name: "Jimmy", species: "fish" }];

let animalsNames = animals.map(animal => animal.species === "dog" && animal.name)
                          .filter(Boolean);
console.log(animalsNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let animals = [
  { name: "Fluffykins", species: "rabbit" },
  { name: "Caro", species: "dog" },
  { name: "Hamilton", species: "dog" },
  { name: "Harold", species: "fish" },
  { name: "Ursula", species: "cat" },
  { name: "Jimmy", species: "fish" }
];

const x = animals.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr.species === 'dog') {
    acc.push(curr.name);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(x);
```

but it isn't really any more readable than just using map and filter

```js
let animals = [
  { name: "Fluffykins", species: "rabbit" },
  { name: "Caro", species: "dog" },
  { name: "Hamilton", species: "dog" },
  { name: "Harold", species: "fish" },
  { name: "Ursula", species: "cat" },
  { name: "Jimmy", species: "fish" }
];

let animalsNames = animals
                    .filter(animal => animal.species === 'dog')
                    .map(dog => dog.name);

console.log(animalsNames); // [ 'Caro', 'Hamilton' ]
```

And `map` is returning `Undefined` in spots because something has to be returned for every iteration.  You're not returning anything when the dog species isn't dog so it returns `Undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Here, use a filter and then a map. 
Adapting is easy for the output you want.

```js
let animals = [
  { name: "Fluffykins", species: "rabbit" },
  { name: "Caro", species: "dog" },
  { name: "Hamilton", species: "dog" },
  { name: "Harold", species: "fish" },
  { name: "Ursula", species: "cat" },
  { name: "Jimmy", species: "fish" }
];

const getNames = (species) => animals
                                .filter(({ species: s}) => species === undefined || s === species)
                                .map(({ name }) => name);

console.log("Dogs");
console.log(getNames('dog'));

console.log("Cats");
console.log(getNames('cat'));

console.log("All");
console.log(getNames());
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in array methods can't do both a `.filter()` and a `.map()` in one operation or even with only one pass through the array, but it might be nice to create a utility function that could both map and filter with only a single pass through the array:

```
// takes callback(item)
// if return value is undefined, then item is removed from output array
// if return value is anything else, then that becomes the output element
function filterMap(array, callback) {
    let result = [];
    for (let item of array) {
        let r = callback(item);
        if (r !== undefined) {
           result.push(r);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then, you could accomplish your operation with a single pass through the array:

```
filterMap(animals, (item) => {
    if (item.species === "dog") {
        return item.name;
    }
});
```

Or, all together in a working snippet you can run here:

```js
// takes callback(item)
// if return value is undefined, then item is removed from output array
// if return value is anything else, then that becomes the output element
function filterMap(array, callback) {
    let result = [];
    for (let item of array) {
        let r = callback(item);
        if (r !== undefined) {
           result.push(r);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

let animals = [
  { name: "Fluffykins", species: "rabbit" },
  { name: "Caro", species: "dog" },
  { name: "Hamilton", species: "dog" },
  { name: "Harold", species: "fish" },
  { name: "Ursula", species: "cat" },
  { name: "Jimmy", species: "fish" }
];

let dogs = filterMap(animals, (item) => {
    if (item.species === "dog") {
        return item.name;
    }
});

console.log(dogs);
```